# "Can't allocate vector of size..." error even though memory.limit() and memory.size() are much higher

Tags: r, memory, ram

I want to run a random forest on my data e.g.

```
# fit a random forest model (using ranger)
rf_fit <- train(as.factor(y_variable) ~ ., 
                data = training_set, 
                method = "ranger")
```

which returns:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5.8 Gb
```

but

```
memory.limit()
```

returns:

```
[1] 20000
```

and

```
memory.size()
```

returns the slightly smaller value (but still bigger than 6GB) of:

```
[1] 18785.67
```

So why can't it allocate the memory?

Comment: Probably you already have other stuff in memory so when you try to allocate the 5.8 GB it doesn't fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is the "last straw" of memory allocation. So even though you have 20GB of RAM, *at the point where it needs to allocate another 6GB* there is not enough available. That could be because you already have objects taking up space, or because the random forest model is allocating memory for several objects, the total of which is bigger than 20GB.